# Buttons in GenericTile don't fire on press

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have two buttons in generic tile. Buttons have onBtn1Press and onBtn2Press function. In my scenerio I want to disable onTilePress function and enable onBtnXPress functions, but when I press button onBtn1Press or onBtn2Press functions doesn't fire. How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" 
        header="{/title}"
        subheader="{/subTitle}" 
        press="onTilePress">
        
        <TileContent footer="{/resource}" unit="">           
            <NumericContent value="{/number}" icon="{/icon}" />
                <content>
                    <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding equalColumns" width="100%">
                        <FlexBox class="columns">
                            <Button text = "Button1" press = "onBtn1Press" type = "Accept">
                                <layoutData>
                                    <FlexItemData
                                        growFactor="1"
                                        baseSize="0"
                                        backgroundDesign="Solid"
                                        styleClass="sapUiTinyMargin" />
                                </layoutData>
                                </Button>
                                <Button text = "Button2" press = "onBtn2Press" type = "Accept">
                                <layoutData>
                                    <FlexItemData
                                        growFactor="1"
                                        baseSize="0"
                                        backgroundDesign="Solid"
                                        styleClass="sapUiTinyMargin" />
                                </layoutData>
                                </Button>
                        </FlexBox>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
                </content>
        </TileContent>    
</GenericTile>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: Does onTilePress fire?

Comment: Yes, onTilePress working.

Comment: What UI5 version are you targeting? As far as I know, tiles are only "presentational", maybe they are not the best suit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consider a sap.f.Card instead (if your UI5 version is greater than 1.64). It is more flexible and not only presentational: you can have all kinds of controls in the card content.

EDIT

In older UI5 version your best shot (AFAIK) is to attach a browser event via javascript to your buttons and stop the event propagation like this:

```
oButton.attachBrowserEvent("click", function(oEvent) {
     oEvent.stopPropagation();
     //Your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm using SAP UI5 ver. 1.52. I cannot change version to greater :( So I have to use generic tile.

Comment: I edited my answer for you UI5 version. I don't know if is a viable solution for you... maybe rethinking your UI coud be an easier option ;-)

Comment: I have decided to change UI and use Dialog with two buttons showing on press Tile instead putting buttons in Tile. Thanks @Cmdd for help :)

Comment: Good choice ;-)